# How to add a TextView to a ScrollView

Tags: java, android

I am trying to render (an unknown) amount of messages into a scrollable list. I'm creating a `TextView` with the message as text and a url that the message is related to as `onclick` action, however I can't get the `TextView` to render in my view.

I've tried to add the `textView` using the `.addView` method, after getting the `scrollView` ID. This didn't work, as the `scrollView` remained `null` even though the id was found.

My `renderMessage` method gets the view passed on from the `onClick` event, which is stored in the `View view`.

The xml code for the mainactivity is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="#2196F3"
        android:forceDarkAllowed="false"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:text="@string/headerTitle"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/logTokenButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="@string/msgTokenButton"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/messageInsertionPoint"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/logTokenButton"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.239">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" />
    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:onClick="syncMessages"
        android:text="@string/sync_messages_button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/logTokenButton"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

```
    TextView textView = new TextView(applicationContext);
    textView.setText(msg.getMessage());

    if (msg.getLink() != null) {
        final pushMessage finalMsg = msg;
        textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                 intent.setData(Uri.parse(finalMsg.getLink()));
                 applicationContext.startActivity(intent);
                 }
            });
        }

        ScrollView scrollView = view.findViewById(R.id.messageInsertionPoint);
        scrollView.addView(textView, 0, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    }
```

The error code I get is:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.mypackage.notifications, PID: 10449
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:390)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574) 
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) 
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ScrollView.addView(android.view.View, int, android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams)' on a null object reference
        at com.myclass.notifications.messageManipulation.renderMessages(messageManipulation.java:54)
        at com.myclass.notifications.MainActivity.syncMessages(MainActivity.java:41)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574) 
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Comment: can you post the xml for the Main Activity, looking at the error, I think the issue with the id.

Comment: Added it in, the ID is the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ScrollView` is null, most probably you referenced wrong `android:id` of view. Or the view is in another layout or something similar

**Edit**:
ScrollView can have only one child. Say a `LinearLayout`. Then you can add other views to that `LinearLayout` dynamically.

```
    LinearLayout summary = findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
    summary.addView(age_table_populate());

    View age_table  = LayoutInflater.from(ResultActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.age_table,null,false);

    TextView input=(TextView)age_table.findViewById(R.id.title);
    String age_table_label = "label";

    input.setText(age_table_label);

    summary.addView(age_table);
```

Comment: Yes, that was it. via the getrootview it was resolved. However, now it says that scrollview can only have one direct child, which is something that seems weird to me.

Comment: what do you mean by **how would I go from the button to the main view? ** I think it might be a different question. You should consider asking a new question

Comment: @niedem and a suggestion. when a topic is resolved, you shouldn't just edit the question to another question or ask in comments. rather, accept the answer and asked further question if needed. TC

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot! The android view still confuses me a bit sometimes, so its great that people like you are so helpful!